# Drawing route on map while changing the markers/pins?

Tags: android, google-maps

Am trying to draw route on maps dynamically when user drags the pins. I can draw route between two geopoints, but not able to draw road route between them.

Am using [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/src/com/commonsware/android/maptouch/NooYawk.java) code to place pins on map which is using `ItemizedOverlay`. And I used the following snippets to get the kml file and to get the consecutive geopoints on the road from source and to destination.

```
public static String getUrl(double fromLat, double fromLon, double toLat,
        double toLon) {// connect to map web service
    System.out.println("getting URL");
    StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
    urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");
    urlString.append("&saddr=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString(fromLat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(fromLon));
    urlString.append("&daddr=");// to
    urlString.append(Double.toString(toLat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(toLon));
    urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
    return urlString.toString();
}
```

And

```
url = new URL(urlString.toString());
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.connect();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    document = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());

    if (document.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").getLength() > 0) {
        String path = document.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection")
                .item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild()
                .getNodeValue();
        if (path != null && path.trim().length() > 0) {
            String[] pairs = path.trim().split(" ");
            String[] lngLat = pairs[0].split(","); 
            if (lngLat.length < 3)
                lngLat = pairs[1].split(",");
            GeoPoint startGP = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6),
                    (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));
            GeoPoint gp1;
            GeoPoint gp2 = startGP;
            for (int i = 1; i < pairs.length; i++) 
            {

                lngLat = pairs[i].split(",");
                gp1 = gp2;

                gp2 = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6),
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));
                map.invalidate();
                final float[] results = new float[3];
                Location.distanceBetween(gp1.getLatitudeE6()/1E6, gp1.getLongitudeE6()/1E6, gp2.getLatitudeE6()/1E6, gp2.getLongitudeE6()/1E6, results);
                distance += results[0];
```

Here I need to add those geopoints (gp1&gp2) to the overlays to draw on map by overriding `draw()` method. Once I get those geopoints I can draw the route. But not able to send geopoints. Stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_icons_draggable.html) I put together of driving directions from draggable markers, and [another](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_revgeo.html) that reverse geocodes the dragged marker.  These examples were created before draggable driving directions were added to the API, so there might be an easier way to do it now.